# ASP.NET dynamically added button click event doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, button, gridview

In my webform app I have gridview with SQLDataSource. Now, I need to add  button dynamically into one cell of each row (button must have value of cell) of this gridview. I added button for each cell, and also added click event for these buttons. But when I click these buttons click event doesn't work. Can everyone help?

```
protected void gvEmployee_RowDataBound(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = e.Row.Cells[8].Text;
            if (e.Row.Cells[8].Text == "1")
            {
                btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                btn.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            e.Row.Cells[8].Text = "";

            btn.Click += btn_Click;
            e.Row.Cells[8].Controls.Add(btn);

        }

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        }
```

Comment: try this  btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

Comment: I tried also this, btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click), but it doesnt work, is there another ways?